# Use Action delegate to call correct function based on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, action, func

I have seen this pattern/approach used before, and I'm trying to recreate it to make some of my existing code more efficient.

**The Use Case:** 
A complex object is retrieved from a source system. Only a subset of the information will be used by the client, so we must 'map' this complex object to a simple POCO for JSON serialization; additionally, in this mapping method, some other data formatting is done. First, we pass our complex object into a generic method that does some basic processing

```
// Generic Method, Entry Point for mapping
static void GenericEntry<T, TK>(string userid, string environment, DBContext context) {

    .... // do stuff with userid and environment to set a context
    .... // query results, which return a complex object of Type TK

    // Here is where I would like to use an Action delegate to call the appropriate map
    // method.. there could hundreds of objects that map and process down to a POCO, 
    // Currently, this logic is using reflection to find the appropriate method with 
    // the appropriate signature... something like: 
    Type functionType = typeof(DTOFunctions);
    var methods = functionType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    var mi = methods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "MapObject" && 
        x.ReturnType == typeof(T));

    if (mi == null) throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Unable to find method MapObject for {0}", typeof(TK).Name));

    var resultList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (var row in results)
    {
        var poco = mi.Invoke(functionType, new object[] { row });
        resultList.Add(poco);
    }
    if (resultCount == -1) resultCount = resultList.Count;
    return SerializeDTO(resultList, ResponseDataTypes.JSON, resultCount);

    // THERE HAS TO BE A BETTER WAY STACKOVERFLOW! HALP!
} 

public Class DTOFunctions {
    // Mapping Method from Complex to Simple object
    static SimplePOCO_A MapObject(ComplexObject_A cmplx){
        var poco = new SimplePOCO_A(); 
        .... // mapping from cmplx field to SimplePOCO field
    }

    static SimplePOCO_B MapObject(ComplexObject_B cmplx) {
        var poco = new SimplePOCO_B(); 
        .... // mapping from cmplx field to SimplePOCO fiel
    }
}
```

Comment: another aspect of this is that the object property names between the complex and simple objects may not be the same, part of the logic and purpose is to make the JSON package that is passed to the caller as small as is possible. I just wanted to stave off any questions concerning "why" I need the mapping function.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to write all of this yourself? Why don't you use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started)?

Comment: I use automapper when the objects are effectively 1 - to - 1, but there are times when the conversion process needs to do some heavily lifting, and I didn't see a way where Automapper helped me there. It could totally be my ignorance though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but is something like this what you want?

```
static void GenericEntry<T, TK>(string userid, string environment, 
                                DBContext context, Func<T, TK> conversion) 
{
    //....
    var resultList = new List<TK>();
    foreach (var row in results)
    {
        var poco = conversion(row);
        resultList.Add(poco);
    }
    //....
}
```

Called as:

```
 GenericEntry<ComplexObject, SimplePOCO>(userid, environment, context, DTOFunctions.MapObject)
```

(Note the lack of `()` in the argument).

Comment: Yes! This works! Great answer and a great way to stop using reflection.

Comment: As a bonus, it'll tell you at compile time whether it can't find a version of `MapObject()` which supports the particular translation you're attempting.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you could maybe implement the [Proxy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) here. 
Otherwise, maybe move the logic to the actual objects themselves and add a ToJSON() method in each of the ComplexObjects that knows how to serialize itself. Then append them together to make the JSON array. This will depend on what you're using to serialize the JSON, so in the example below, I've just done it manually.

The common JSONSerializable  interface

```
    public interface IJsonSerializable
    {
        string ToJson();
    }
```

The Complex and simple objects:

```
    public class ComplexObjectA : IJsonSerializable
    {
        public string ToJson()
        {
            var simpleObject = new SimpleObjectA();

            // Map away

            // Then serialize
            return SerializeDTO(simpleObject);
        }

        private string SerializeDTO(SimpleObjectA simpleObject)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class SimpleObjectA
    {
        // simple properties
    }
```

And then entry point

```
        static void GenericEntry<T, TK>(string userid, string environment, DBContext context)
        {

            // Magic happens here
            var results = GetResults();

            // More magic

            var resultList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var row in results)
            {
                var poco = row.ToJson();
                resultList.Add(poco);
            }
            return String.Format("[{0}]", String.Join(resultList, ", "));
        }
```